# Maple don't solve equations

Tags: math, linear-algebra, maple

I am trying to solve these  equations:

S := solve({                                                                                              PVA1+PSA1+PPA1=1,                                                                                                               PVA2+PSA2+PPA2=1,                                                                                         PVA3+PSA3+PPA3=1,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             PVA1*0.2+PVA2*0.5+PVA3*0.3=0.3,                                                                                          PSA1*0.2+PSA2*0.5+PSA3*0.3=0.2,                                                                                          PPA1*0.2+PPA2*0.5+PPA3*0.3=0.3}, Explicit=true) ;

But maple gives S := NULL. Any ideas? PS equations have some solutions.

Comment: I don't know Maple, but it looks to me like you have nine variables and only six equations, which can't be solved.

Comment: You can get a least squares fit for an assumed solution and calculate what its correlation is.

Answer (score 3):

The linear system as you have posted it is inconsistent.  You can check this out for yourself by writing:

> with(LinearAlgebra):
>
> eqns := [PVA1+PSA1+PPA1=1, PVA2+PSA2+PPA2=1, PVA3+PSA3+PPA3=1, PVA1*0.2+PVA2*0.5+PVA3*0.3=0.3, PSA1*0.2+PSA2*0.5+PSA3*0.3=0.2, PPA1*0.2+PPA2*0.5+PPA3*0.3=0.3]:
>
> M := GenerateMatrix(eqns, indets(eqns), augmented=true):
>
> LinearSolve(M);

```
Error, (in LinearAlgebra:-LA_Main:-BackwardSubstitute) inconsistent system
```

To see exactly why it is inconsistent look at the last row resulting from

> ReducedRowEchelonForm(M);